# Getting ord() to read from a file

Tags: python, list, ord

What my code does is it counts the amount of times a letter has appeared and counts it to the respected letter. So if A appears two times, it will show 2:A. My problem is that i want it to read from a file and when ord() tries to, it cant. I dont know how to work around this.

```
t=open('lettersTEst.txt','r')
tList=[0]*26
aL=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

idx=0


for char in t:
    ch=ord(char)
    if ch >=65 and ch <= 90:
        pos=int(ch)-65
        tList[pos]+=1

for ele in tList:
    print(idx, ": ", tList[ch])
    idx+=1
```

Comment: I hope this is an exercise.  There are lots of lower case letters not in the range 65-90.  - Grüßen!  (Greetings! in German).

Comment: yeah, its not that serious. Its more of a practice for the midterm.

Comment: ```open``` returns a file object.  What do you *get* when iterate over a file object?  Try adding ```print(char)``` as the first line in the ```for``` suite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you iterate over a file you get lines. If you want characters you need to iterate over each line as well.

```
for line in t:
    for char in line:
        ch = ord(char)
        ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to loop over the indivdual characters of the each line of the file, and you could use a `Counter` instead of an array.

And if you want uppercase characters only, then add `if char.isupper()` before you add to the Counter.

Example

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter()
>>> with open('lettersTEst.txt') as f:
...     for line in f: 
...         for char in line:
...             c[char] += 1
...
>>> for k,v in c.items():
...     print('{}:{}'.format(k,v))
...
a:2
 :4
e:1
g:1
i:3
h:1
m:1
l:1
n:1
p:1
s:4
r:1
t:2
```

Comment: This does not do the same thing as the OP is trying to do though, they are only keeping a count for capital letters.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Sure. The if statement can be added. Hence, I said *example*

Answer (score 1):

While I prefer @JohnKugelman's answer over my own, I'd like to show two alternate methods of iterating over every character of a file in a single for loop

The first is using the second form of [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) using a callable (read one character) and a sentinel (keep calling the function until it returns this value) In this case I'd use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to make the function that reads one byte:

```
import functools

read_a_byte = functools.partial(t.read, 1)
for char in iter(read_a_byte,''):
    ch = ord(char)
    ...
```

The second is frequently used to flatten two dimensional lists, [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) takes something that is iterated over (the file) and chains each generated value (each line) together in iteration.

```
import itertools
char_iterator = itertools.chain.from_iterable(t)
for char in char_iterator:
    ch = ord(char)
    ...
```

Then you could pass either to `collections.Counter` to construct a basic counter but it wouldn't follow the same logic you have applied with `ord`:

```
read_a_byte = functools.partial(t.read, 1)
c = collections.Counter(iter(read_a_byte,''))

>>> pprint.pprint(dict(c))
{'a': 8,
 'b': 2,
 'c': 9,
 'd': 4,
 'e': 11,
 ...}
```